# wxpython Accessing an object from an ID

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.7

Each object created in a wxPython app undergoes the creation of an `id`. It can be given as a parameter or is created using `id=wx.NewId()` automatically.

As I understand it, with an object's `id` you can then reference that object from elsewhere, but i cannot find any simple explanations of how this is done.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or perhaps shed some light on this?

(Note:  I am not looking to bind events via the ID, that is the only tutorial I have found all over the place.)

Comment: Im not sure ... Ive been using wx extensivly for a long time and have never gotten by id ... typically you encapsulate everything into classes that have access to what they need ... you could write some kind of wrapper/factory function around constructors to store the id in a global dictionary for later lookup ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is a builtin way of doing this ... but you could do something like this

```
my_ids = {}

def widget_factory(widget_class,parent,id,*args,**kwargs):
     w = widget_class(parent,id,*args,**kwargs)
     my_ids[id] = w

def get_widget_by_id(widget_id):
     return my_ids[widget_id]
```

apparently there is a function...

http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#FindWindowById

Comment: @joran..
OK, so regarding the linked fuction, how then would i call it.  THe function is a function of class window.  So to get the window associated with id wxSomeID   ... bah   open interperator and try myself...stupid comment

Comment: so call it on your main frame maybe ?

Comment: @joran...
lol...Just tried three versions.  One calling the function on the object in question (redundant since if we know the object in question there is no purpose).....Two calling on wx.Window.FindObjectById(###) (it dint like me because there was no instance of Window class to generate the self data for the function call).....Three called it on parent level object  test=frame.FindWindowById(###) (succeeded)....four test=frame2.FindWindowById(###) (frame 2 not in family tree of our mystery object)(fails with no return (possibly returned None???)  So props and answer credit to you! ThankYou!

Comment: glad to help sounds like you got it :) ... I really like wx It is great

Answer (score 4):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I extracted this answer from the OPs question. [Answers should not be contained in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/316262).</sub>

---

#### Answer provided by [Jase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658512/jase), but based on the [answer by Joran Beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12537455/4298200) :

The function `FindWindowById()` found in the class `wx.Window`, which most widgets are subclasses of.

By calling this function on an objects parent (haven't tried grand parent etc.) it returns a pointer (copy?) of the object in question such that: (in the interactive interpreter)

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
but = wx.Button(frame, -1, label='TestButton')
frame2 = wx.Frame(None)

butId = but.GetId()
test = wx.Window.FindWindowById(butId)         # Fails with TypeError
  # TypeError: unbound method FindWindowById() must be called with Window instance as
  # first argument (got int instance instead)
test = Frame2.FindWindowById(butId)            # returned either a None object or nothing at all.
test = Frame.FindWindowById(butId)             # returned a pionter (copy?) of the object in such a
  # manner that the following worked:
label = test.GetLabel()
print label                                    # displayed u'TestButton'
```

Thus by knowing an `id` of an object it is possible to get a pointer to the object so that it can be processed further.